# Fixing the 100% accuracy with DecisionTreeClassifier in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use decision tree for classification and get 100% accuracy.

It is a common problem, described [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/is-a-100-model-accuracy-on-out-of-sample-data-overfitting) and [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/35713/i-got-100-accuracy-on-my-test-set-is-there-something-wrong?newreg=82108f30a7cd4b70955cd0cd4600a8f5). And in many other questions.

Data is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BroTLgp3-F39pIjEeGhIN9-woFqsLC3AB89XgC0nN5k/edit?usp=sharing).

Two best guesses:

- I split data incorrectly
- My dataset is too imbalanced

What is wrong with my code?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import sklearn.model_selection as cv
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as MSE
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score 

# Split data
Y = starbucks.iloc[:, 4]
X = starbucks.loc[:, starbucks.columns != 'offer_completed']

# Splitting the dataset into train and test 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, 
                                                    test_size=0.3,
                                                    random_state=100) 

# Creating the classifier object 
clf_gini = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini", 
                                  random_state = 100, 
                                  max_depth = 3, 
                                  min_samples_leaf = 5) 

# Performing training 
clf_gini.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicton on test with giniIndex 
y_pred = clf_gini.predict(X_test) 
print("Predicted values:") 
print(y_pred) 

print("Confusion Matrix: ", confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)) 

print ("Accuracy : ", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)*100) 

print("Report : ", classification_report(y_test, y_pred)) 

y_pred_gini = prediction(X_test, clf_gini) 
cal_accuracy(y_test, y_pred_gini) 


Predicted values:
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
Confusion Matrix:  [[36095     0]
                    [    0  8158]]
Accuracy :  100.0
```

When I print X, it shows me that `offer_completed` was removed.

```
X.dtypes

offer_received               int64
offer_viewed               float64
time_viewed_received       float64
time_completed_received    float64
time_completed_viewed      float64
transaction                float64
amount                     float64
total_reward               float64
age                        float64
income                     float64
male                         int64
membership_days            float64
reward_each_time           float64
difficulty                 float64
duration                   float64
email                      float64
mobile                     float64
social                     float64
web                        float64
bogo                       float64
discount                   float64
informational              float64
```

Comment: I am afraid that `starbucks.columns != 'offer_completed'` does not remove the target variable from you `X`. You should use something like `[c for c in starbucks.columns if c!='offer_completed']`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, @FBruzzesi. Can you please elaborate? Not sure to write this line properly. Thanks!

Comment: @FBruzzesi, I think that column is dropped, I updated the output.

Comment: Just use `X = starbucks.drop(columns=['offer_completed'])` to make sure it is dropped. But also your code should drop the col, even if it is not the "panthonic" ;) way to do it. Could you upload your `starbucks` data somewhere so we can test your code?

Comment: @FBruzzesi But the `df.columns` object is not a `list`, it is a `pd.Index` instance. And for `pd.Index`, equality check is implemented as inclusion check, thus it should work. F.i. for a `df` with the columns `[a, b, c]`, `df.columns` returns `Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')` and `df.columns != 'b'` returns `array([ True, False,  True])`.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't know such trick. Thank you for clarifying that. Then the data should be fine, @AnakinSkywalker you can expect a leak in the data. Try to do some data exploration before applying models.

Comment: @Scotty1, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BroTLgp3-F39pIjEeGhIN9-woFqsLC3AB89XgC0nN5k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your are welcome! But you are definetely right that such comparisons should be avoided. I strongly vote for using **explicit** dropping, possibly raising errors for missing columns (and to catch typos), over implicit dropping. To check for data leaks, I'd recommend starting with checking `starbucks.corr()`.

Comment: @FBruzzesi, thanks. I did, it is highly correlated, I guess. I am thinking how to deal with it. A mix of numeric and boolean variables. But I would not expect 100% anyway. I think this is more a technical error.

Comment: Found the leak, added as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fitting the model and checking feature importances you can see that they are all zeros except for `total_reward`. Then investingating such column you get:

```py
df.groupby(target)['total_reward'].describe()
    count   mean    std    min   25%    50%   75%    max
0   119995  0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0
1   27513   5.74    4.07   2.0   3.0    5.0   10.0   40.0
```

You can see that for target 0, `total_reward` is always zero, otherwise has a value always greater than 0. Here's your leak.

As there could be other leaks and it is tedious to check each column, we can use a sort of "predictive power" of each feature alone:

```py
acc_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col', 'acc'], index=range(len(X.columns)))

for i, c in enumerate(X.columns):

    clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini", 
                                 random_state = 100, 
                                 max_depth = 3, 
                                 min_samples_leaf = 5) 
    
    clf.fit(X_train[c].to_numpy()[:, None], y_train)
    
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test[c].to_numpy()[:, None])
    acc_df.iloc[i] = [c, accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)*100]


acc_df.sort_values('acc',ascending=False)
                 col      acc
8       total_reward      100
4     completed_time  99.8848
13  reward_each_time  89.3205
14        difficulty  89.3205
15          duration  89.3205
21          discount  86.4054
19               web   85.088
20              bogo  84.4801
3        viewed_time  84.4056
2       offer_viewed  84.3491
18            social  83.3525
1      received_time  83.0497
7             amount  82.5436
0     offer_received  81.7526
16             email  81.7526
17            mobile  81.6464
11              male  81.5651
10            income  81.5651
9                age  81.5651
6   transaction_time  81.5651
5        transaction  81.5651
22     informational  81.5651
12   membership_days  81.5561
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts! Am I just dropping it then?

Comment: Not sure that I got your tip. In that column `total_reward` I have different values. So, I am very new to ML.

Comment: Yes, you should drop all the information that you would not expect to have if the target column is unknown - in this case total_reward could be just be a target aswell. Consider to iterate the process above if other "weird" result occur. Addressing your second comment: yes it has different values but it is constant (zero) on one target value and constant (>0) on the other target value. I guess you can think of it as: "Knowing that the total reward is >0 implies that there has been a reward"

Comment: Nice one @FBruzzesi! @Anakin: Yup, either drop it or predict for total reward if you want to have a prediction with more information (and assuming accuracy is good for this prediction).

Comment: Looking into other features like `completed_time` and `reward_each_time`, the same problem occurs. You should drop all columns which share the 0/non-zero behaviour of your target column.

Comment: Thanks, gents. Still does not work, but it will not work at 4 AM. My brain does not work first. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! Yep, there are still too many columns with too strong correlation. Check `starbucks.corr(method='spearman')['offer_completed']`. (spearman is rank corr., thus checking for monotonic relation and not only linear corr. as pearson.) Any value above `>.8` is suspicious, values `>.9` are highly suspicious.

Comment: Since the target is binary correlation may not be the best metric to use to check leaks. I am adding a workaround to check feature by feature.